# Why do separate "paste" event listeners both paste to the same <div>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

At least under the latest release of Chrome for Windows, the *paste* event listener is giving me inconsistent results.

I'm attempting to listen for *paste* events from two column divisions on the screen and allow the user to paste text to one column or the other depending on where he/she clicked last.  For some reason, pasted text always goes to the righthand column.

It was noted that I could use `<input>` instead of `<p>` for this, but once the user pastes text I want my script to respond to clicked-on words of the pasted text and AFAIK `<input>` does not allow that.

Any experience, help, or workarounds appreciated, thanks.

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/yuxuqad)**

Tested with Chrome, Version 63.0.3239.132, under Windows 7 Pro, Chromium latest release under Ubuntu.

---

### Update, 1/12/18:

Following [advice from @Grant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48176254/5025060) (below), I inserted content into my two `<div>`s and Chrome began accepting paste actions for both of them.  Moreover, Firefox, which had not been responding to paste actions anywhere in the window, now also began accepting 
pasted text to both columns.

Meanwhile, **the examples I've published here still hold true,** and I would like to know why: is this "expected" behavior, or just an implementation problem with the paste event for these browsers?

---

```js
// Listen for "paste" events in each column:
//
document.getElementById("leftColumn").addEventListener("paste", leftPaste, false);
document.getElementById("rightColumn").addEventListener("paste", rightPaste, false);

// todo: for some reason leftPaste() is not triggered:
//
function leftPaste(e) {
    var clipboardData, pastedData;
    clipboardData = e.clipboardData;
    pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
    alert(pastedData);
    document.getElementById('leftPara').textContent = pastedData;
}

function rightPaste(e) {
    var clipboardData, pastedData;
    clipboardData = e.clipboardData;
    pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
    alert(pastedData);
    document.getElementById('rightPara').textContent = pastedData;
}
```

```css
body {
    color : #334455;
    background-color: #aabbcc;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size : 14px;
    cursor : default;
}

.frame {
    border: 1px solid rgb(31, 40, 49);
    background-color : #283849;
    color : #aabbcc;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.myColumn {
    height: 90vh;
    overflow: auto; /*causes scrollbars*/
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    margin-left: 4%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Text pasted to left column goes to right column</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h3>With Google Chrome, Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) under
    Windows Pro 7 64 bit,
    clicking and pasting in either column pastes to the right column.
   </h3>
  
    <div id=leftColumn class="myColumn frame">
        <p id=leftPara style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;" class=clickable></p>
    </div>
    <div id=rightColumn class="myColumn frame">
        <p id=rightPara style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;" class=clickable></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: likely its because a div really isnt an input field so it just gets set there.

Comment: If you switch the `<p>` to `<input>` it works.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielA.White and @MisterMystery, but I need to make text clickable within the <div> so I can't use <input>.  Also, it gets stranger: if I wrap the two column <divs> in `<div     style="width: 910px; height: 300px; margin-left: auto;">`, the left column begins receiving pasted text _but only after the user clicks and pastes text from outside either column_.  I've posted a live demo of this at http://jsbin.com/cazime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't definitively tell you *why* this behaviour is this way - maybe someone smarter can, but I have encountered situations before where a div needs to actually have content within it for that div to be focusable. Here is a pen demonstrating the desired outcome: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QaQBPV. - The text "Left." and "Right." makes it focusable individually.

```
<div id=rightColumn class="myColumn frame">
  Right <!-- this bit -->
    <p id=rightPara style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;" class=clickable></p>
</div>
```

The event firing on the parent div when wrapping the divs is due to something called event bubbling, which you had set to true, I changed that to false in the pen (the last parameter in the event listener) - see http://alistapart.com/article/domtricks2 for more info.

Comment: Thank you.  As you say, this doesn't answer my question, but it does fix my problem.  I don't agree with you on the event bubbling part though, as I didn't at any time have my event listeners' last parameters set to true.  Interestingly, placing content within the `<div>`s as you have done not only caused Chrome to behave correctly, it also caused FireFox to begin accepting pasted text where it formerly did not respond at all to _paste_ events.